# Java Getting a point on the edge of a circle after 3 axis rotation.

Tags: java, math, vector, 3d, geometry

Edited To be simplier

Right down to it i need to rotate a circle on 3 axis in a 3D space. I've go the y axis down without issues. However, my work with the other two have only resulted in the circle going around the center point instead of rotating. As well i need to be able to find a point around the edge of this circle after rotation. That way i can plot my objects to be at those points or render effects at that point.

Example of what i have so far... the context is in a minecraft mod as its an easy place to test code graphically. http://puu.sh/38Z6x.jpg I'm using 6 points for testing the code but can increase it later.

Here is the code i have so far [-Code-](https://github.com/DarkGuardsman/Dark-Library/tree/master/src/minecraft/dark/library/orbit) its github so it will change as often as i sync my code. So don't rely on it on what i've tried but rather the structure i'm using. Last sync i was trying spherical coordinate system as an option.

I'm also looking for preformance tips for doing these calculation. I'm going to have several of these calculations running on the project i'm working on controlling 1000s of moving objects.

Comment: I usually use matrices for 3d transformations. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Never used matrices before for rotation, most of the time i handle it threw sin, cos, etc. I'll read the wiki link you gave me but, could you explain how to use one in this instance.

Comment: You can fairly easily perform affine transformation in 2D without matrices.  In the 3D case, there's not really a reasonable alternative, however.  The only caveat to that last sentance is that if you restrict yourself to rotation, you can use quaternions.

Comment: 2D i have no issue with as i can get it to rotate using sin and cos. With 3D i can do this as well as long as i only rotate around the y axis. I almost got it working for the other two axis however the circle moved around the center point instead of only rotating.I'll have to read up on quaternions as I've only used those once in physics.

Comment: If you want to make local rotations, you need to first subtract the centroid position of the circle so that it is centered on the origin.  For a local rotation: subtract centroid position, apply transforms, add centroid position again.

Comment: [Here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html) is a great quaternion tutorial for beginners that I often link.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tutorial was just starting to break down an equation on using quaternions. Best to follow a tutorial to better my understanding of it. As well i've already started the methods off to use the origin then get the offset. This way i can just call this method and add it to my current vector.

Comment: @Aggieboy You wouldn't happen to know a working example using quaternions for rotation in java. I've got my code mostly done but have messed up somewhere. It would really help if i had something to compare it to see which part needs more work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my simple Quaternion class.  It uses a lot of the semantics found in [this](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/3d/quaternions.html) tutorial:

```
public class Quaternion {
    public double w, x, y, z;
    public Quaternion(double angleRadian, double x, double y, double z){
        double dAngle=angleRadian/2; //might as well divide by 2 here
        this.w=Math.cos(dAngle);
        this.x=x * Math.sin(dAngle);
        this.y=y * Math.sin(dAngle);
        this.z=z * Math.sin(dAngle);
    }
    public Quaternion(){
        x=y=z=0; w=1;
    }
    public void norm(){
        double magnitude = Math.sqrt(w*w + x*x + y*y + z*z);
        w = w / magnitude;
        x = x /  magnitude;
        y = y / magnitude;
        z = z / magnitude;
    }
    public Quaternion conj(){
        Quaternion ans = new Quaternion();
        ans.set(this);
        ans.conjLocal();
        return ans;
    }
    public void conjLocal(){
        x=-x;
        y=-y;
        z=-z;
    }
    public void set(Quaternion q){
        w=q.w;
        x=q.x;
        y=q.y;
        z=q.z;
    }
    public void set(double w, double x, double y, double z){
        this.w=w;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.z=z;
    }
    public Quaternion mult(Quaternion q){
        Quaternion ans = new Quaternion();
        ans.w = (this.w*q.w - this.x*q.x - this.y*q.y - this.z*q.z);
        ans.x = (this.w*q.x + this.x*q.w + this.y*q.z - this.z*q.y);
        ans.y = (this.w*q.y - this.x*q.z + this.y*q.w + this.z*q.x);
        ans.z = (this.w*q.z + this.x*q.y - this.y*q.x + this.z*q.w);
        return ans;
    }
    public void multLocal(Quaternion q){
        Quaternion temp=this.mult(q);
        this.set(temp);
    }
    public String toString(){ return "<"+w+", "+x+", "+y+", "+z+">"; }
}
```

To rotate a vector `v` by quaternion `q` to get a resulting vector `v'`, the following equation must be used:

```
v' = q * v * q.conj()
```

Here is a demonstration that rotates a vector (or position coordinate) around a quaternion.

```
public class QuaternionExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
         * Let's say we have a vector <1,0,0>, and we want to rotate it
         * such that the result will be in the other unit axiis: <0,1,0>
         * and <0,0,1>.  Right hand rule applies for rotating about an axis!
         * Convince yourself of the following through mental imagery:
         * 1. For <0,1,0>, we want to rotate <1,0,0> by 90 degrees about the z axis
         * 2. For <0,0,1>, we want to rotate <1,0,0> by 90 degrees about the -y axis (or -90 degrees also works)
         */

        //the quaternion form of a 3d vector is simply <0,Vec3> or <0,x,y,z>
        Quaternion x=new Quaternion(); 
        x.set(0,1,0,0);

        //1, we want <0,1,0>
        Quaternion rot = new Quaternion(Math.PI/2,0,0,1);
        System.out.println( rot.mult(x).mult(rot.conj()) );

        //2, we want <0,0,1>
        rot = new Quaternion(Math.PI/2,0,-1,0);
        System.out.println( rot.mult(x).mult(rot.conj()) );
        rot = new Quaternion(-Math.PI/2,0,1,0);
        System.out.println( rot.mult(x).mult(rot.conj()) );
    }
}
```

I wanted to rotate my vector (or position coordinate) around the origin.  If I wanted to rotate it about a different point (for instance, an object's centroid `c`), I would need to subtract the centroid of the object first, and then add it to the result:

```
v' = q * (v-c) * q.conj() + c
```

Comment: Ok so my Quaternion class looks about the same as yours. i've add some way to use normal degress for rotation. Though i'm starting to think this might be my issue as i'm using degrees instead of radians https://github.com/DarkGuardsman/Dark-Library/blob/master/src/minecraft/dark/library/math/Quaternion.java                    https://github.com/DarkGuardsman/Dark-Library/blob/master/src/minecraft/dark/library/orbit/NetworkOrbit.java

Comment: I see you are using Euler angles, and those tend to be very arbitrary and confusing.  For instance, you could be using X-Y-Z Euler angles, or Z-X-Y, [ect...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles).  Additionally, I suspect the Euler angles you are getting are *global*, in which case you can't simply add a yaw offset in `getOrbitOffset` in hopes that it is equates to a *local* yaw adjustment.  Convert the Euler angles to Quaternions, left-multiply a quaternion created by 'FromAxis` representing a yaw rotation, and use that to transform the coordinates.

Comment: Ok i will try that seeing as i just fixed an issue with my line renderer.

Comment: Ok i'm getting somewhere now with the quaternions however i think i'm inputting radius wrong. When using quaternions how would i do the radius of the circle i would be rotating. http://puu.sh/39Yej.jpg

Comment: You will either define the radius or the centroid, but not both.  The reason is because rotating an arbitrary point around a centroid already has its radius defined by the distance between the point and the centroid.  I think rotating around a centroid will be easier and more flexible than using an orbit radius (if you want 5 objects to orbit a point, you'd have to name different radii for each one).  If possible, could you provide some code snippets of how you are doing the *entire* calculation in one instance?  I think I could better assist you with that.

Comment: I got the radius by changing it to use a starting vector with a distance from the center point. Then i rotate this point by my object spacing in radians. So i've got that working which my issue turned out to be i was getting my spacing in meters and not in radians. http://puu.sh/3ae63.jpg My new issue is i can't seem to rotate around the circle after setting the spacing rotation

Answer (score 0):

Ok looks like i got it working and have got my rotation working almost 100%. Only issue i'm having is i can't rotate around the circle's edge after setting my line spacing. http://puu.sh/3ae63.jpg Thank you @Aggieboy for your help its been great

Here is my code though i think it needs more work but its something. The github classes will be updated as i work on them more. However, i can't link the github file to the test class due to it being a private repo.

```
/*
         * This is the code used to test the rotation by generating a circle with the radius
         * given
         */
        double r = 3;
        double s = (2 * Math.PI) / this.points.length;
        Vector3 vec = new Vector3(this.xCoord + 0.5D, this.yCoord + 2D, this.zCoord + 0.5D);
        boolean flip = false;
        /*
         * Rotation speed is set here though it could be control by anything. As well the
         * rotation change is stored in a vector(x,y,z) and doesn't only have to be in the z axis
         */
        this.rotation.z += 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        {
            Color color = flip ? Color.red : Color.blue;
            Vector3 point = vec.clone().add(NetworkOrbit.getOrbitOffset(r, s * i, this.rotation));
            points[i] = point.clone();
            if (i != 0)
            {
                int a = i + 1 == this.points.length ? 0 : i - 1;
                int b = i;
                /*
                 * generatelaser creates a laser line from one point to another and is used for
                 * visual debug
                 */
                this.laser.generateLaser(this.worldObj, points[a], points[b], color, 10, 5);
            }
            flip = !flip;
        }
        this.laser.generateLaser(this.worldObj, points[this.points.length - 1], points[this.points.length - 2], flip ? Color.red : Color.blue, 10, 5);
        //Markers to show me the center point and then a  line to point 0
        this.laser.generateLaser(this.worldObj, vec, vec.clone().add(new Vector3(0, -2, 0)), Color.darkGray, 10, 5);
        this.laser.generateLaser(this.worldObj, points[0], vec, Color.darkGray, 10, 5);
```

Github code links sorry for the format by i can't seem to post more than 2 links just yet
https://github.com/DarkGuardsman/Dark-Library/blob/master/src/minecraft/dark/library/...

...math/Quaternion.java

...orbit/NetworkOrbit.java